# using System.Data is not recognized in the newer version of UWP

Tags: xml, uwp, dataset, system

Is working well in the older version of UWP. Any feedback?

DataSet is not recognized. I could not import data from xml.

Comment: import System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: What is your Min version? It needs to be at least RS3 I think.